# Powerpoint paste option from other applications

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

In MS Word, there is an option to choose the pasting behavior between the same application and different applications. It's under the Office button->word options->advanced.

However I don't see the same option for Powerpoint. Is there one available? I hate it when they don't make it consistent between apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is **No**.

By using `Paste Special` option, you can choose between keeping the source formatting or pasting text only. This is your only chance to have control over Paste behavior in Powerpoint.

Comment: BTW I was asking for powerpoint, not outlook. But I suppose your answer is applicable to Powerpoint. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. My answer's for Powerpoint.